# How do programmatically slide (using transitions) to another route after n seconds in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to build a mobile first webapp which requires me to show a splash page for a few seconds before transitioning automatically to the login page using a slide effect. This should only happen with the splash page.

I don't want to create an overlay on the login page itself as I would want to able to perform some actions on the splash page which I would like to be independent from other pages.

The other thing that I would like to do is prevent users seeing the splash page again if they try to manually navigate to it but I think I can handle that with an authentication HOC but the route transition effect is more important for now.

I've been looking at React CSS transitions but I'm confused and have not found anything that would serve my purpose.

This is my code:

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Route,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'

import Home from './homeComponent';
import Login from './loginComponent';

const App = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

homeComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HomeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12"><h1>Home</h1></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeComponent;
```

loginComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LoginComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12"><h1>Login</h1></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginComponent;
```

What would be the right approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

you can set a timeout on the componentDidMount lifecycle hook of the splash screen to change the route to the login page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HomeComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.history.push('/login')

      /* here you could run a function passed by the main container in the props
         where you can change the state of the parent component to mark the splash
         screen as showed, and redirect directly to the login page or the page after 
         that if already logged */

    }, 5000 /* or the time you want in miliseconds */)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12"><h1>Home</h1></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeComponent;
```

this.props.history.push('/login') is the action creator provided by react-router.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas how to add a transition effect for this one page?

Comment: And `this.props.history.push('/login');` worked instead of `this.props.push('/login')`.

Comment: Sebastián Espinosa No problem. Was just highlighting. :)